# Django stacked inline admin question

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

Using Django 1.2 I have a stacked inline admin with a many to many field on it. I need to limit the choices in the many to many based on the parent object that the inline exists for. For example, I have a `WidgetPart` inline that's on the `Widget` admin. When I'm editing an existing `Widget` I need to limit `WidgetPart.foo` choices based on logic pertaining to the `Wiget` that is being edited. I can't seem to do this with `formfield_for_manytomany`, as not only does it not provide any `obj` related information, but it's `request` argument seems to always be `None` when used in an inline. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this on your InlineAdmin class:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
  if db_field.name == "foo":
    kwargs["queryset"] = SomeModel.objects.filter(something=something)
    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)

  return super(YourModel, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```